# Migrating to null safety: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

After migrating to null safety,  I'm getting the error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>'. Thanks for helping out.

```
                                FutureBuilder(
                                  future: usersReference
                                      .doc(sublist[i].ownerId)
                                      .get(),
                                  builder: (context, snap) {
                                    if (!snap.hasData) {
                                      return loader();
                                    }
                                    UserModel user =
                                        UserModel.fromDocument(snap.data);//error line
                                               //tried snap.data(), snap.data!
                                    return Container();
                              );
```

This the UserModel

```
class UserModel {
  String id;
  String username;
  String url;

  UserModel(
      {
      required this.id,
      required this.username,
      required this.url,
     });

  factory UserModel.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return UserModel(
      id: doc.id,
      username: doc.get('username') ?? "",
      url: doc.get('url') ?? "",
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the prototype of "UserModel.fromDocument" ?

Comment: Have you tried using `as` or adding a type on your FutureBuilder?
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> or  UserModel user = UserModel.fromDocument(snap.data as DocumentSnapshot);

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to cast it?

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
       future: usersReference
               .doc(sublist[i].ownerId)
               .get(),
       builder: (BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
         if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return loader();
         }
        UserModel user = UserModel.fromDocument(snap.data);
        return Container(); 
       }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to adding type cast if u have to make sure it type.